# z-index, убрать блоки под родителя

Tags: css, position

как убрать блоки линий за серый фон снизу, если этот фон для них родитель, а блоки с отрицательным margin? Пробовал z-index, не получается. Т.к они являются чаилдами серого фона
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
             <div class="lineItems">
                <div class="line profitLine">
                    <span class="firstLine">Линия</span>
                    <span class="secondLine">Прибыли</span>
                </div>
                <div class="line stabLine">
                    <span class="firstLine">Линия</span>
                    <span class="secondLine">Стабильности</span>
                </div>
                <div class="line infLine">
                    <span class="firstLine">Линия</span>
                    <span class="secondLine">Бесконечноти</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: а где css?код   ...

Answer (score 0):

SimaDmtr, `z-index` работает вместе с `position`. К примеру:

```css
.parent{
  position:relative;  
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:red;
  margin:100px auto;
}
.child{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:-20px;
  left:-20px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```